# Update to Xcode 7 from Xcode 6

Tags: swift

I have start to develop my App with Xcode 6, if i update to  Xcode 7, my App will work as well?

(Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0)

(I used Swift 1.2 to code my App with Xcode6.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will work fine, in Xcode 7 just do the following to convert from swift 1.2 to 2.0, From Xcode menu go to:

```
Edit> Convert > to Latest Swift Syntax.
```

Good luck !

Comment: Please let me know if anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your app will work but you will need to change some syntax for that.

For change code automatically when it's possible you can do this :

```
Edit >> Convert >> To Latest Swift Syntax...
```

If it may helps you, see what's change in new version : [swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015//?id=106)